# How to make player walk through layers of 2d fog smoothly?

Tags: unity, 2d, shaders, sprites, graphic-effects

I'm trying to recreate the fog effect that Graveyard Keeper has, with several layers, so taller objects will get less fog. I'm using the approach described here:
[the devs post on Gamasutra](https://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/SvyatoslavCherkasov/20181023/329151/Graveyard_Keeper_How_the_graphics_effects_are_made.php)

The problem with this approach is when the player is walking through each layer, it comes in front of the fog, and the fog effect "pops away", as the fog is thicker on the bottom of the fog layer. See the image where the fog is a little exaggerated.

I'm using Unity and all layers are in the "Default" sorting layer, and Y as the custom sort axis, so sprites higher up are behind lower sprites.

The jarring effect is worse the thicker fog I have.

How can I solve this, so the player doesn't "blink" like this? Thanks!

[image]
[image: Graveyard keeper setup]

Comment: Are you sure the character should walk through the fog and not just have the multi layer fog always in front of the object?

Comment: It looks to me like they're drawing their sprites with alpha test/cutout, rather than smoothly antialiased edges with alpha blending. That lets them write their sprites to the depth buffer, and use the depth information to fade individual pixels of the fog sprite as an object approaches it from behind, so they reach 0 alpha at the moment the pop would happen, hiding it. Is that an option for your game?

Comment: @Zibelas It can be always in front of the player, but it needs to go in front and behind of objects, so taller objects have less shadows on top, due to the more dense fog on the bottom.

Comment: @DMGregory Very interesting, I have no experience on depth buffers and the techniques your suggesting is beyond my current skill level. But I'll look into it, and try to find some technical person to help me. Thanks :)

Comment: Answers here can help, if you can live with the sharp stairstep edge you get from the aloha testing needed for that technique (or if you have some good antialiasing post-processing that can mitigate this)

Comment: I have faced the challenge of implementing a similar effect for HTML5 Canvas, were you cannot do what @DMGregory suggests. If you want to keep things simple, have a layer of fog always on top, with some transparency, then have the layers with some transparency too, but accounting for the always of top layer. You can tune the values until you get a visually pleasant result. There will be some "popping", but mitigated. How well mitigated, depends of how well you tune it.

Comment: More: It's not physically inaccurate. The thick layer of fog may be shorter than the payer sprite, but free fog particles would normally be way above that horizon, and affect how the scene is lit.

Comment: @HatoruHansou — want to post that information as an Answer below?

Comment: @DMGregory Let's wait for comments from the OP first. To reformat my comment as answer, the OP has to relax the requirement of having the "exact result" from the article at Gamasutra. I'm proposing to mitigate the popping, not eliminating it. But I don't sure the OP is fine with it. For now, I'm attempting to convince the OP of going that path.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. The article doesn’t explain how to solve this specific issue, but it could be a solution to have an extra fog layer/color over the player only, and somehow try to calculate when the player passes a fog layer and set the opacity. Was that what you were suggesting? That would be required on most NPC and moving items. If you show an image of what you mean it would help too. Thanks!

Comment: @BlueGooGames Basically, yes. But why only over the player? I'd mean over all the scene. Except you need only over the player for some reason. My original idea was to throw a semi transparent fog layer on top of the scene, that layer never will be behind the player sprite. All the others fog layers behave the same as they are now. I will try to produce a gif showing it.

Comment: Ok I see, with less thick fog on the ”depth fog” and a layer of fog on top would make the effect less jarring, so it might work.

Comment: @BlueGooGames, Yes. While I cannot leak my assets (yet) for various reasons, I produced a demo using assets from opengameart.org. I will show that it doesn't look so bad as long as you put some effort into tune the values. The tuning isn't reutilizable, because it will depend on your assets. So I won't give my exact values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the OP stated that depth testing isn't a good option, I propose a simpler approach based on z-index alone, with tuned parameters to hide the "abrupt transition effect".

Render 0: yellowish solid color layer always on top

[image]

Render 1: removed the always on top layer (for comparison). The fog is neutral gray, the top layer changed the mood of the scene before, maybe too much.

[image]

Render 2: exaggerated fog intensity, no always on top layer (for comparison)

[image]

Some considerations:

If we impose ourselves no buffer access, no low level OpenGL/other APIs calls, no custom shaders, we are a bit limited in what we can do.

The asset used for the fog is provided to examine it. It can be improved, for example: borders must be softer. Suggestion: play with Blur effects and other filters.

The original fog assets came from here: https://opengameart.org/content/thick-fog

The original character assets came from here: https://opengameart.org/content/tmim-heroine-bleeds-game-art

The fog asset is 1024 pixels wide. For our fog, I took a rectangle of 1024x85, very close to the top of the original fog full image.

To avoid artifacts when two rows of fog intercept in the y axis, I used the Gimp lasso tool to round borders, including the bottom border, and then blur bottom and top borders.

While each fog row is 85 pixels in height, their are separate from each other by 20 pixels in the y axis. We want overlapping to have a better continuity effect, but borders must be taken care of with proper blurring, for example. Rough borders won't do. The ones here aren't perfect either and probably only useful for testing.

The rows move at different speeds. The speed table is:

```
var speed_table = [1, 0.5, 2, 0.25, 0.75, 1.25]
```

The loop that instantiates the rows cycle through that table, and if it reach the end it starts at the beginning again. This is needed because there are more fog rows than entries in the speed table.

Formula to determine how many rows we need:

```
rows = viewport_height / row_distance_y
```

The resulting fog row asset:

[image]

Because that image is nearly all transparent, this other version serves to appreciate it better:

[image]

But the first one is the one that must be used for experimentation.

All of these parameters, the height of the fog, the separation of 20 pixels, the alpha of the pixels, all must be played with until ideal ones are found. In the first render, for example, the top layer hides the fog rows too much, somewhat defeating its purpose.